# Selecting all rows who belong to a group with some properties

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL for a web application, and I've run into a type of query I can't think of a way to write efficiently.

What I'm trying to do is select all rows from a table which, when grouped a certain way, the group meets some criteria. For example, the naive way to structure this query might be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table T
    JOIN (
        SELECT iT.a, iT.b, SUM(iT.c) AS sum
        FROM table iT
        GROUP BY iT.a, iT.b
    ) TG ON (TG.a = T.a AND TG.b = T.b)
WHERE TG.sum > 100;
```

The problem I'm having is that this effectively *doubles* the time it takes the query to execute, since it's essentially selecting the rows from that table twice.

How can I structure queries of this type efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a window function although I don't know if it is more efficient. I guess it is as it avoids the join. Test this and your query with `explain`

```
select *
from (
    select
        a, b,
        sum(c) over(partition by a, b) as sum
    from t
) s
where "sum" > 100
```

Comment: This works beautifully. I had never heard of window functions before, but they do exactly what I wanted, and the overhead of using them seems to be extremely small. Thanks! :)